# Sum up tensor of different shape

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

So i am doing some new work on the Forward Forward algorithm using ConvNet, here is the original paper [forward forward](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.13345.pdf)  when performing prediction i will need to sum up the goodness score for each layer, the problem is each of this scores have different dimension since the Convolution operation has been performed on the data, here is my code sample.

```
def predict(self, x):
        goodness_score_per_label = []
        for label in range(self.output_dim):
            # perform one hot encoding#
            print('label:', label, x.shape)
            encoded = overlay_y_on_x(x, label)
            goodness = []
            for idx, layer in enumerate(self.layers):
                encoded = layer(encoded)
                print('encoded:', encoded.shape)
                goodness += [encoded.pow(2).mean(1)]
                print('goodness:', len(goodness), goodness[idx].shape)
            goodness_score_per_label += [sum(goodness).unsqueeze(1)]
        goodness_score_per_label = torch.cat(goodness_score_per_label, 1)
        return goodness_score_per_label.argmax(1)
```

here is the tensor dimension,

```
encoded: torch.Size([50000, 6, 14, 14])
goodness: 1 torch.Size([50000, 14, 14])
encoded: torch.Size([50000, 16, 7, 7])
goodness: 2 torch.Size([50000, 7, 7])
encoded: torch.Size([50000, 120, 3, 3])
```

i am getting the error from this line `goodness_score_per_label += [sum(goodness).unsqueeze(1)]` what is the best way of handling this problem?

Comment: Do you want the sum to be performed across spatial dimensions, or over the whole tensor?

Comment: @Ivan i am looking the who tensor, but i will also like to look at the performance of summing across spatial dimensions too.

Comment: According to [the abstract of the Foward-Forward Algorithm paper by Hinton](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.13345.pdf), "The sum of
the squared activities in a layer can be used as the goodness"
So the sum of squared activations should end up as a scalar, no dimensions, right? Check how you're taking the goodness of each layer.

Comment: looking at other implementation of the https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.13345.pdf forward forward paper, i think your problem might be how you are computing the layer, you can fill in layer be to have the same dimensions as layer a, does that work for you or  you can go for a direct same convolution i guess.

Comment: @Allaye, I think all I want so how to sum up the layer results as they have different shapes.

Comment: you cant sum up tensors what different dimensions, pytorch cant infer which axis to work on i think, you will have to make some sacrifice that might affect your results i think, let me come up with a same convolution operation for you, i think that might be the best option for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you could approach this problem, but the best way is you use a same convolution, with this you are guaranteed to have the same output dimensions after the operation, you dont have to try and force layers to conform to the dimensions of other layers.

```
class CustomConBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding, bias=True, device="cuda"):
        super(CustomConBlock, self).__init__()
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.padding = (self.kernel_size - 1) // 2  # this is what you are missing
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, self.kernel_size, stride, self.padding, bias=bias).to(device)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, self.kernel_size, stride, self.padding, bias=bias).to(device)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU().to(device)
        self.batchnorm = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels).to(device)
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2).to(device)

    def forward(self, input):
        # perform your network forward pass here or whatever you want
        # now all the conv layers will have the appropriate dimensions 
        
        return None
```